# MATLAB writing csv with mixed alphanumeric strings, scalar arrays, nans

Tags: matlab, csv, export-to-csv

Ok, coming from Python and never having used MATLAB before, it seems like it is unnecessarily hard to write data to a csv using MATLAB...

So my data looks like this:

```
col1       A2A    B2   CC3     D5
asd189     123    33   71119   18291
as33d      1311   31   NaN     1011
asd189     NaN    44   79      191
```

It has N header columns that are made of alphanumeric strings.
It has a leftmost column of length M which is made of alphanumeric strings.
It has an (M-1) x (N-1) array of NUMERIC data, with possible NaNs.

Can you please provide code to write this to a csv? I cannot use the xlswrite function because I'm on a cluster without Excel installed. Really just want to get on with the actual data analysis. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can only write matrices (not cell arrays) directly using `csvwrite`, and as you say you need Excel installed for `xlswrite`, so that leaves you with low level operations. You can see a walkthrough for writing to text files [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/write-to-delimited-data-files.html#br2ypq2-1), and code for your example below:

```
% Initialise example cell array
M = {'col1',  'A2A', 'B2', 'CC3',  'D5'
     'asd189', 123,  33,    71119, 18291
     'as33d',  1311, 31,    NaN,   1011
     'asd189', NaN,  44,    79,    191};
% Open a file for writing to (doesn't have to already exist, can specify full directory)
fID = fopen('test.csv','w');
% Write header line, formatted as strings with comma delimiter. Note \r\n for new line
fprintf(fID, [repmat('%s, ', 1, size(M,2)-1),'%s\r\n'], M{1,:});
% Loop through other rows
for row = 2:size(M,1)
    % Write each line of cell array, with first column formatted as string 
    % and other columns formatted as floats
    fprintf(fID, ['%s, ', repmat('%f, ', 1, size(M,2)-2),'%f\r\n'], M{row,:});
end
% Close file after writing
fclose(fID);
```

Result:

[image: csv]

Answer (score 0):

Use [`writetable`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writetable.html). It makes writing to CSV (or to an Excel file, or to other text-delimited file formats) much easier than using `csvwrite`, or `xlswrite`, or low-level commands such as `fprintf`.

```
>> t = table({'asd189';'as33d';'asd189'},[123;1311;NaN],[33;31;44],[71119;NaN;79],[18291;1011;191]);
>> t.Properties.VariableNames = {'col1','A2A','B2','CC3','D5'}
t = 
      col1      A2A     B2     CC3      D5  
    ________    ____    __    _____    _____
    'asd189'     123    33    71119    18291
    'as33d'     1311    31      NaN     1011
    'asd189'     NaN    44       79      191
>> writetable(t,'myfile.csv')
```

If your data is currently not stored as a table (maybe it's in an array or cell array), it's pretty easy to convert to a table using utility functions such as `array2table` or `cell2table`. You will only pay a small time penalty for doing this.

PS - you don't need Excel to be installed in order to write to an Excel file. You may not be able to read them afterwards, but MATLAB can still write them. But it sounds like you'd prefer .csv anyway.